# How do i manage custom props like 'isInnerPage' within router reducer?

Tags: reactjs, redux, connected-react-router

I use `connected-react-router` and have some types of pages: main, inner, auth, admin. Depends of current page type I render certain components. Now it works in this way: there are 4 props in my `config` reducer with bool values: `isMainPage, isInnerPage, isAdminPage, isAuthPage`, and only one of them could be true in a time. They changes any time I change location (by executing certain action in `componentDidMount`). So, I want to deal with `connected-react-router` and, if possible, pass these props from config reducer to the router. Then, if possible, I want to execute an action that will define current page type and set it and then I would get this val in components. Is it all possible? Sorry for this explanation - I'm just studying.

I would provide some code but I don't know which part could be helpful - ask for one, please

config reducer:

```
import {
    SET_VIEW_MODE,
    SET_AUTH_PAGE,
    SET_MAIN_PAGE,
    SET_INNER_PAGE,
    SET_ADMIN_PAGE,
...
} from '../constants';

...
        case SET_AUTH_PAGE:
            return {
                ...state,
                isAuthPage: true,
                isMainPage: false,
                isInnerPage: false,
                isAdminPage: false
            };

        case SET_MAIN_PAGE:
            return {
                ...state,
                isAuthPage: false,
                isMainPage: true,
                isInnerPage: false,
                isAdminPage: false
            };

        case SET_INNER_PAGE:
            return {
                ...state,
                isAuthPage: false,
                isMainPage: false,
                isInnerPage: true,
                isAdminPage: false
            };

        case SET_ADMIN_PAGE:
            return {
                ...state,
                isAuthPage: false,
                isMainPage: false,
                isInnerPage: false,
                isAdminPage: true
            };
```

config actions:

```
...imports;

export const actionSetViewMode = () => ({ type: SET_VIEW_MODE });

export const actionSetAuthPage = () => ({ type: SET_AUTH_PAGE });

export const actionSetMainPage = () => ({ type: SET_MAIN_PAGE });

export const actionSetInnerPage = () => ({ type: SET_INNER_PAGE });
```

expample of component that sets any type:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { actionSetMainPage } from '../actions/configActions';
...

class MainPage extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.actionSetMainPage();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                ...
            </>
        )
    }
}

export default connect(null, {
    actionSetMainPage,
})(MainPage);
```

example of component that renders any depends of page type:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { CSSTransition } from 'react-transition-group';
import Subaction from '../components/header/Subaction';
import Back from '../components/header/Back';
import Menu from '../components/header/Menu';
import Title from '../components/header/Title';
import Logo from '../components/header/Logo';
import Notification from '../components/header/Notification';

class Header extends Component {
    render() {
        const { isAdaptive, isAuthPage, isMainPage, isInnerPage, title } = this.props.config;

        return (
            !isAuthPage &&
            <header>
                <div className="h-inner">
                    ...
                    {
                        isMainPage && 
                        <Logo></Logo>
                    }
                    <Notification></Notification>
                    ...
                </div>
            </header>
        )
    }
}

export default connect(state => ({
    config: state.config
}), {})(Header);
```

Comment: Please make your question more specific and provide some code showing what you've tried. This is your best change to get some help, because the answer to "is it possible" is probably just "yes".

Comment: I have added an example

Comment: I can't help with your actual question, but I'd like to point out that `MainPage` doing `   this.props.actionSetMainPage();}` in its `componentDidMount` is a sign that your overall architecture is not ideal. MainPage shouldn't have to signal to redux that it is in fact a "main page". The outer code that is in charge of mounting MainPage in the first place should be aware of what page types are and when they're mounted. Routing code in general is rather declarative, not imperative. Maybe consider a different architecture.

Comment: I have tried to change a type by listening `LOCATION_CHANGE` from `connected-react-router` but I don't think it this is a good way

Comment: well, I just need a key in store like 'pageType', but I don't know, what is a typical way to do it - these two ways (define it by mounting or listening `LOCATION_CHANGE` and bind it depends of url) are not good i suppose